# For finite extension $L|K$of local fields, the valuation $v_L$ extends $v_K$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm reading Jurgen Neukirch's Algebraic Number theory, p.317~318 ( proof of class field axiom for local fields) and some question arises.

Let $L|K$ be a finite (possibly cyclic) extension of local field. Here local field means, a field which is complete with respect to a discrete valuation and have a finite residue class field. Or equivalent to finite extensions of the $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and $\mathbb{F}_p((t))$.

Let $v_L$ and $v_K$ be the (normalized) discrete valuation on $L$, $K$, respectively.

My question is, $v_L$ extends $v_K$?

1. For the case that $L$, $K$ are of $p$-adic number fields ; i.e., finite extensions of the fields of $p$-adic numbers $(\mathbb{Q}_p , v_p)$, it seems that it can be proved that $v_L$ extends $v_K$.

Because, in this case, from the proof of his(Neukirch's) book p.135, (5.2)-proposition and p.133, the exponential valuation $w_L$ and $w_K$ on $L$, $K$ are given by

$$ w_L(\alpha)=(1/n_L)v_p(N_{L|\mathbb{Q}_p}(\alpha)), n_L := [L : \mathbb{Q}_p]$$
$$ w_K(\beta)=(1/n_K)v_p(N_{K|\mathbb{Q}_p}(\beta)), n_K := [K : \mathbb{Q}_p]$$

Then for $\beta \in K$, we can show that $w_L(\beta)=w_K(\beta)$ by using

(1) separability of $L|K$ as being extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ ,

(2) his book p.10, (2.7)-Corollary,

(3) his book p.9, (2.6)-proposition (iii),

(4) Hungerford, Algebra, p.286, Prop.6.12

(5) $1/n_K = (1/n_L)[L:K]$.

; i.e., for $\beta \in K$,

$$ w_L(\beta) := (1/n_L)v_p(N_{L|Q_p}(\beta)) = (1/n_L)v_p(N_{K|Q_p} \circ N_{L|K}(\beta))
   = (1/n_L)v_p(N_{K|Q_p}(\prod_{\sigma \in Hom_{K}(L,\bar{K})}(\sigma \beta)) 
= (1/n_L)v_p(N_{K|Q_p}(\beta^{[L:K]}))
   = (1/n_L)v_p((N_{K|Q_p}(\beta))^{[L:K]})= (1/n_L)[L:K]v_p(N_{K|Q_p}(\beta)) 
= (1/n_K)v_p(N_{K|Q_p}(\beta))$$.

2. Next Question is, for the case that $L$, $K$ are finite extensions of $\mathbb{F}_p((t))$(another local field case), is it also true that $v_L$ extends $v_K$? Perhaps we may apply similar strategy above ?

Comment: Why the switch from $v$ to $w$? What normalization are you using? If it’s “the image is $\mathbb{Z}$ for both fields”, then $v_L$ will not extend $v_K$: it’s the phenomenon of *ramification*, which should be explained at length in the book long before class field theory. I’d definitely expect it to make very precise how valuations behave over finite extensions of non-Archimedean fields, $p$-adic or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your notation means that $v_K$ is the normalization of $w_K$. You have given a valid proof that $w_L$ extends $w_K$, but this does not imply that $v_K$ extends $v_L$ (and indeed this is not true in general).

Here's an example: take $K=\mathbb Q_p$ so $v_K=w_K$ is the usual $p$-adic valuation on $\mathbb Q_p$, and take $L=\mathbb Q_p(p^{1/n})$. We have $n\,w_L(p^{1/n})=w_L(p)=w_K(p)=1$ and therefore $w_L(p^{1/n})=1/n$. Now the issue is that when you change from $w_L$ to $v_L$, i.e. you normalize, you define it so that $v_L(p^{1/n})=1$ since $p^{1/n}$ is a uniformizer of $L$, but then $v_L(p)=n\neq 1=v_K(p)$.

The result you're asking about is true when $L|K$ is *unramified*: in this case the ramification indices $e(L|\mathbb Q_p)$ and $e(K|\mathbb Q_p)$ are equal, call this value $e$, and then $v_L=e\,w_L=e\,w_K=v_K$.

Also for your question 2, yes everything we've argued works analogously when $L$ and $K$ are extensions of $\mathbb F_p((t))$, the only thing to be careful of is that you have the right definition of $N_{K|\mathbb F_p((t))}$, as many authors define this in a way that is only correct for separable extensions.

Comment: Can I ask some technical(?) question? 1) Are $p$, $p^{1/n}$ prime elements(uniformizer) of $K:=\mathbb{Q}_p$, $L:=\mathbb{Q}_p(p^{1/n})$ respectively? 2) For the argument in the case of unramified extension, where can I find associated reference? What page?  3) For our question 2,  the extension $L|\mathbb{F}_p((t))$ and $K|\mathbb{F}_p((t))$ are separable? If not, how can we argue 'analogously'? Why you answer 'yes'?

Comment: Some confusion : Your wrote, "Here's an example : ~~~ i.e., you normalized, you define it so that $v_L(p^{1/n})=1$ since $p^{1/n}$ is a uniformizer of $L$, ~~" Why "$p^{1/n}$ is a uniformizer of $L$" guarantees that $v_L(p^{1/n})=1$? I know the concept of a prime element (In the Neukirch's book, p.121) : i.e. , $\pi \in  \mathcal{O}$(valuation ring) such that $v(\pi)=1$. It seems that the concept of prime element depends the normalized valuation.. And you state that $p^{1/n}$ is a uniformizer of $L$. Uniformizer of valuation ring is a prime element?

Comment: Uhm..I'm understanding the concept of uniformizer of $L$ as a generator of the unique maximal ideal of the valuation ring of $L$. So It seems that the concept of uniformizer of $L$ depends on some (normalized) valuation. My question is, when you state that "$p^{1/n}$ is uniformizer of $L$", what valuation you refered to?

Comment: p.s. Perhaps.. for every exponential 'normalized' valuation $v_K$ on $K$, the unique extension  $w_L$ on $L$ defined as $w(\alpha) = (1/n)v_K(N_{L|K}(\alpha))$ (Neukirch's book p.133) is also normalized valuation?

Comment: What I want to say is, possibility of falsity of $v_L(p^{1/n}) = 1$ ; maybe, there is a possibility that $p^{1/n}$ is not uniformizer with respect to $v_L$ (or $w_L$). Am I pointing out properly?

Comment: @Plantation a uniformizer of a discrete valuation ring is the same as a prime element. The valuation on $L$ is $w_L$, which gives a valuation ring $\mathcal O_L$, and this valuation ring does not change when we normalize $w_L$.

Comment: @Plantation $w_L$ is not already normalized; it is normalized if and only if $L|K$ is unramified. Check page 150 of Neukirch: if $w_L$ was already normalized then the definition given $e=(w_L(L^*):w_K(K^*))$ would always be $1$.

Comment: I think you're thinking about the definition of uniformizer wrong. The definition of a uniformizer should be the following: if $L$ is a valued field then $\pi\in\mathcal O_L$ is a uniformizer if it generates the maximal ideal $\mathcal m_L$. This doesn't change when you normalize the valuation, and if $v_L$ is normalized this is equivalent to the condition $v(\pi)=1$. But without being normalized these aren't the same; this is why we have $w_L(p^{1/n})\neq 1$ even though $p^{1/n}$ is a uniformizer.

Comment: The same page of Neukirch shows that $\pi_L$ being a uniformizer of $L$ is equivalent to the condition that $\pi_K \sim \pi_L^e$ where $e$ is the ramification index. But $e\le n$ in general and we've shown in our example that $e\ge n$ so $e=n$ in the example, and you indeed have $p=(p^{1/n})^e$ so $p^{1/n}$ is a uniformizer in $\mathbb Q_p(p^{1/n})$ (it is completely unambiguous that $p$ is a uniformizer of $\mathbb Q_p$).

Comment: O.k. Let me follow your comment. Define $w_L=(1/n)v_K \circ N_{L|K}$. For explicitly, denote $\mathcal{O}_{(L,w_L)}$ be the valuation ring of $L$ induced from the $w_L$. And denote $^{a}w_L := v_L$ be the associated normalization from $w_L$. 1) Then $\mathcal{O}_{(L,w_L)} = \mathcal{O}_{(L,^{a}w_L)}$. 2) If $w_L = ^{a}w_L$ (normalized), then $w_L(L^*)=\mathbb{Z}$. 
  3) And there exists a prime element $\prod \in \mathcal{O}_{(L,^{a}w_L)} $ such that $^{a}w_L(\prod)=1$.

Comment: 4) And as you answered, $w_L(p^{1/n})=1/n$. (If $p^{1/n}$ is a prime element of $\mathcal{O}_{(L,w_L)}$, then 
  $^{a}w_L(p^{1/n})=1$)

Comment: 5) Let $\mathfrak{p}_{(L,w_L)}=\mathfrak{p}_{(L,^{a}w_L)}$ be the associated maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{(L,w_L)}$. Since $\mathcal{O}_{(L,w_L)}$ is discrete valuation ring, uniformizer is same as a prime element ; i.e., $<\prod> = \mathfrak{p}_{(L,w_L)}$ if and only if $^{a}w_L(\prod)=1$.
   
   6) And there is a possibility of existence of $\prod \in \mathcal{O}_{(L,w_L)}$ such that $<\prod> = \mathfrak{p}_{(L,w_L)}$ and $ w_L(\prod)\neq 1$. In this case, $w_L$ is not normalized.

Comment: 7) It seems that point is, such $\prod$ exists? You claim that the $p^{1/n}$ plays the role.  As above, since $w_L(p^{1/n})=1/n \neq 0$, it suffices to show that $<p^{1/n}>= \mathfrak{p}_{(L,w_L)}$.

Comment: 8) My question is, to show this, it suffices to show that $p=\pi_K = \epsilon (p^{1/n})^{e}$ for some unit $\epsilon \in \mathcal{O}_{(L,w_L)}^{*}$, where $e$ is the ramification index? ;i.e., the condition $\pi = \epsilon \prod ^{e}$ in the Neukirch's book p.150 is sufficient to gaurantee that $\prod$ is a uniformizer(prime element)?

Comment: If $p^{1/n}$ plays the such role, then maybe(?) we can prove that $^{a}w_L:=v_L$ does not extends $v_K$. (Am I following well?)

Comment: You understand correctly; and what you've written in point (8) is correct, this condition is sufficient to guarantee that $p^{1/n}$ is a uniformizer of $L$. This is because, by definition of ramification index you have $n=e=(w_L(L^*):w_K(K^*))=(w_L(L^*):\mathbb Z)$. Now $w_L(L^*)$ is an additive subgroup of $\mathbb Q$ which contains $\mathbb Z$ as an index $n$ subgroup, and the only such possibility is $w_L(L^*)=\frac 1n\mathbb Z$. Now you can show that $p^{1/n}$ generates the maximal ideal: if $x\in\mathfrak m_L$ then $w_L(x)>0$, and thus $w_L(x)=\frac{k}{n}$ for some $k>0$

Comment: and thus $w_L(x)\ge w_L(p^{1/n})$ which implies $x\in p^{1/n}\mathcal O_L$ (this is because $w_L(x/p^{1/n})\ge0$ so $x/p^{1/n}\in\mathcal O_L$).

Comment: O.K. It seems that arguing as follows is more correct(?) ; $w_L(L^{*})=w_L(\prod)\mathbb{Z}=(1/e)(v_K(\pi_K))\mathbb{Z}=(1/e)\mathbb{Z}=(1/n)\mathbb{Z}$. (We used Neukirch's book p.150) Anyway thank you~

Comment: Perhaps.. Can you see my other assoicated question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4471414/possibility-of-choice-of-normal-basis-sigma-1w-cdots-sigma-nw-such-tha/4471436?noredirect=1#comment9372406_4471436 ? There, in answering, Arkady mentioned that to show the possibility of choice of normal basis $\{ \sigma_1w \cdots \sigma_nw\}$ such that $w\in \mathcal{O}_L$, "this argument assumes that the valuation on K is chosen to be the unique one extending the valuation on k". From your point of view, is it reasonable?  Neukirch indeed assume that $v_L$ extends $v_K$ ?

Comment: And I asked above previewsly : " 2) For the argument in the case of unramified extension ($v_L=ew_L=ew_K=v_K$), where can I find associated reference? What page? 3) For our question 2, the extension $L|\mathbb{F}_p((t))$ and $K|\mathbb{F}_p((t))$ are separable? If not, how can we argue 'analogously'? Why you answer 'yes'?  "     How about these questions?

Comment: Why ramification indices $e(L|\mathbb{Q}_p)=(w_L(L^{*}) : v_p(\mathbb{Q}_p^{*}))$(?) and $e(K|\mathbb{Q}_p)=(w_K(K^{*}) : v_p(\mathbb{Q}_p^{*}))$ are equal when $L|K$  is unramified?