# If $L|K$ is a finite extension of local fileds, then the valuation ring $\mathcal{O}_K$ is open in $\mathcal{O}_L$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Literally, if $L|K$ is a finite extension of local fileds such that the (normalized discrete) valuation $v_L$ extends $v_K$, then the valuation ring $\mathcal{O}_K$ is open in $\mathcal{O}_L$?

My first attempt is by noting that $\mathcal{O}_K = K \cap \mathcal{O}_L$(?), it suffices to prove that the $K$ is open in $L$. And is it true?

This question originates following proof ( Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory, p.318, class field axiom )

[image]
[image]

(Possibility of choice of such $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_L$ (even we can find $\alpha$ such that $\alpha^{\sigma}:=\sigma(\alpha) \in \mathcal{O}_L$ for all $\sigma \in G(L|K)$) is dealed with [Possibility of choice of normal basis $\{ \sigma_1w \cdots \sigma_nw\}$ such that $w\in \mathcal{O}_L$ (valuation ring of local field)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4471414/possibility-of-choice-of-normal-basis-sigma-1w-cdots-sigma-nw-such-tha/4471436?noredirect=1#comment9372406_4471436), although some technical(?) problem (;i.e., $v_L$ extends $v_K$) exists. If needed I will upload detailed explanation.)

Why the $M$ is open and closed? As our question, if $\mathcal{O}_K$ is open in $\mathcal{O}_L$, then since fintie sum of open sets of topological ring is also open(true?) and finite sum of compact sets is also compact, and compact subsets of hausdorff space is also closed, we are done ; i.e., $M$ is open and closed (Here we used that the valuation ring $\mathcal{O}_K$ is compact(Neukirch's book p.135, (5.1) proposition) and the Local field $L$ is hausdorff- so that the subspace $\mathcal{O}_L$ is also hausdorff-.)

Can anyone helps?

Comment: That underlined comment does *not* mean $\mathcal O_K$ is open in $\mathcal O_L$.  In that comment it is just part of a larger expression.  And have you tried thinking about some actual *examples*?  For instance, do you think $\mathbf Z_2$ is open in $\mathbf Z_2[i]$ or can you find arbitrarily small elements of $\mathbf Z_2[i]$ outside $\mathbf Z_2$ that are close to $0$?  (As an analogy, are open subsets of $\mathbf R$ also open in $\mathbf C$?)

Comment: You'd be better off determining why, if $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ is a basis of $L/K$, then $\sum \mathcal O_Ke_i$ is open in $L$ Think about $\{a + bi : a \in I, b \in J\}$ in $\mathbf C$ where $I$ and $J$ are nonempty open subsets of $\mathbf R$.

Comment: Once again you are posting a question where an essential part of it requires the user to read a screenshot, which makes the question inaccessible to anyone who needs a computer assistant to read questions.  Please consider editing your questions by typing the relevant part from Neurkirch's book (the question only needs a *small* part of the screenshot) so you don't have to rely on image files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, since $K$ is a $1$-dimensional subspace of $L$ as a $K$-linear space, it cannot be open in $L$. (And if $\mathcal O_K$ is open, so is $K$ as the union of $\mathcal O_K$-cosets.)

$L=\oplus_i Ke_i=\prod_i K$ as topological vector spaces over $K$. Hence $\sum \mathcal O_K e_i$ as a product of open/closed subsets must be open/closed (also any open subgroup must be closed as well). This is true for any $K$-basis $\{e_1, \cdots, e_n\}$, and the normal part is irrelevant.

Comment: You mean, using $\Sigma \mathcal{O}_Ke_i \cong \prod_{i}\mathcal{O}_K$? Where the condition $L \cong \prod_i K$ as topological 'vector space over $K$' ( not only just homeomorphism) is used? And..it seems that the normal part ($\alpha^{\sigma} \in \mathcal{O}_L$) is used since we want to show that the $M = \Sigma \mathcal{O}_K\alpha^{\sigma}$ is open(closed) in $\mathcal{O}_L$, not just in $L$.

Comment: $\mathcal O_L$ is open in $L$.

Comment: Uhm.. In general, $\Sigma \mathcal{O}_K e_i$ does not contained in $\mathcal{O}_L$?

Comment: You mean, it's okay if we don't use $\Sigma \mathcal{O}_K e_i \cong \prod_i \mathcal{O}_K$? And $e_i$ is an element of $L$, not in $K$. Why multiplying by $e_i$ is a homeomorphism from $K$ to $K$? (In particular, why $\mathcal{O}_K e_i$ is contained in $K$?) And..you wrote in answer that "Hence  $\Sigma \mathcal{O}_K e_i$ as a product of open/closed subsets~~", what does it exactly means?